# Kendo Grid checkbox disable to edit

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm looking a solution how to disable checkbox to be checked if checked='yes' in my dataSource.

[Full Demo in Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/aWuhavIp)

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { selectable: true, headerTemplate:'<b>Some title</b>' },
    { field: "name" }
  ],
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe", checked:"yes" }, 
                { name: "John Doe", checked:"no" }, 
                { name: "Doe John", checked:"yes" }, 
                { name: "John", checked:"no" } ],
  dataBound:function(e){
    var grid = this;
    var rows = grid.items();

    $(rows).each(function(e) {
      var row = this;
      var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
      if (dataItem.checked == 'yes' ){ 
        grid.select(row); 
        
        //grid.select('disable',true);
        //grid.addClass(".k-state-selected"); 
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. Just add `class` for disabling mouse events on that row.

```
.disabled{
  opacity:0.5;
  pointer-events:none;
}
dataBound:function(e){
  var grid = this;
  var rows = grid.items();

  $(rows).each(function(e) {
    var row = this;
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
    if (dataItem.checked == 'yes' ){ 
      grid.select(row); 
      console.log(row);
      $(row).addClass("disabled");  
    }
  }
```

**Note:** this will disable entire row from any events, if you want you can disable only checkbox by finding inner checkbox element:

```
$(row).find(".k-checkbox-label").addClass("disabled");
```

Your modified example: [Disable checked](https://dojo.telerik.com/obInebiw)